# Intellij IDEA: Should show 1 implement but show 2 implements of a interface

Tags: java, intellij-idea

A class named DefaultGetFreeSchedulePolicyImpl have a field whose type is an interface named `IRemoveSchedulePolicy`, while `IRemoveSchedulePolicy` have 2 implements: `DefaultRemoveFreeSchedulePolicyImpl` and `DefaultRemoveSchedulePolicyImpl`.

```
public class DefaultGetFreeSchedulePolicyImpl {

...

    IRemoveSchedulePolicy removeSchedulePolicy;
}
```

In spring xml, there do exist two version of class `DefaultGetFreeSchedulePolicyImpl` bean configs, but both of them use the same `removeSchedulePolicy` :

```
<bean id="extendsGetFreeSchedulePolicy"
        class="com.xx.xx.xx.policy.freeSchedule.impl.DefaultGetFreeSchedulePolicyImpl">
...
        <property name="removeSchedulePolicy" ref="removeSchedulePolicy" />
    </bean>

<bean id="dateGetFreeSchedulePolicy"
        class="com.xx.xx.xx.policy.freeSchedule.impl.DefaultGetFreeSchedulePolicyImpl">
    ...
        <property name="removeSchedulePolicy" ref="removeSchedulePolicy" />
    </bean>
```

And bean `removeSchedulePolicy` has only one bean:

```
<bean id="removeSchedulePolicy"
        class="com.xx.xx.xx.policy.freeSchedule.impl.DefaultRemoveSchedulePolicyImpl"></bean>
```

Base on information above, I expect that, Intellij IDEA can be as smart as human that, know which bean to go when I want to find the implement of the method, but it didn't:

Is it because I use Intellij IDEA in the wrong way? Is anywhere I can config such that Intellij IDEA can read the Spring bean definition then just show me the right bean method implement?
[image]

Comment: Stupid question: did you activated the Spring plugin?

Comment: @EugenCovaci Yes, I use Intellij IDEA Ultimate

Comment: Please report issue on YouTrack attaching sample project for investigation: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA.